# Are services accessed via External IP address slower than internal IP address when local?

Tags: networking, ip, nas

I've got my NAS at home. Of course, I can access it via the local IP address (192.168.x.x) and the public (remote) IP address (84.x.x.). My only option when I'm outside is via the external IP address, but when I'm at home I can access my NAS via both ways.

However, I'm wondering: Would I notice any speed differences (except perhaps initial connection) when accessing my NAS via the external IP address, instead of the internal IP address when I'm home (local) anyway?

---

For as far as it matters. This regards to my Synology NAS and regards to both the DSM (browser access) as for the apps to connect to the NAS (DS File, DS Video, etc.)

Comment: Depends:  how does the speed of your LAN (mostly set by the kind of cables you use) compare to the speed of your ISP subscription? The two may be radically different: I have a Gb/s LAN, but only a 150Mb/s (in download) outer connection.

Comment: I've got a 40Mbit internet subscription and I get 25Mbit at most with WiFi over the internet. However, I assume my connection speed local is faster than the 25Mbit, using a 802.11N - 300Mbit router connection. Everything is connected with Gigabit cables. Do I answer my own question there?

Comment: You're on the right track. But you need a real measurement. For the WAN, test the real value with speedtest.net, for the LAN download and use iperf, https://iperf.fr/iperf-download.php  Theory cannot trump a real measurement.

Comment: Also, and I apologize, I should have made clear that the outer (WAN) speed you use in transferring files from your NAS to your pc when you are away from home, is your **upload** speed, which for all ADSLs and many FTTx (including me) is significantly lower than the download speed.

Comment: How have you configured your network to allow access to your NAS from inside your network via your public IP address? If your router supports [nat hairpinning/loopback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback) and is configured to use it then there should be no difference in speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably notice that access is considerably slower when you are outside your house.

Inside your home network - you will be connecting at a speed of 100mbps or 1000mbps when connected via a cable, or at 54, 125, 300mbps wirelessly.

When you are outside your house, your NAS will be able to talk to your router - but the information leaving the house, travelling over the internet and reaching you at your remote location will only ever be as fast as the upload speed on your internet connection.

---

When I said probably notice a differnce, there are a few caveats to this:

- It is dependant on the amount and size of files you are working with - a small single file (like a 50kb word document) will be fairly quick regardless of the connection speed internally or externally and you probably won't notice a difference.  Counter to this - streaming a full HD movie will show a huge difference in buffering times if your net connection is slow at home
- your upload speed at home may vary if you have others at home using your connection while you are out of the house - so you may notice a difference in connectivity and speed at different times
- you may have a "superfast" connection (google fibre, virgin fibre) etc - and this could near enough rival a local connection remotely as long as your house's upload and the connection you are on at your remote location as equally as fast
- regardless of connection speeds where you are - if your external interface (home internet connection) is being hammered by torrenting or large file transfers - you will be massively slowed down outside the house but would barely notice it inside the house.

---

[image]

If you consider the image above (please excuse my poor visio skills):

- The Purple Line represents your house (complete with NAS) and may run
  at between 54mbps and 1000mbps.
- The red line represents your routers speed to the internet - upload and download (unknown to me)
- the green line and house represent wherever you are outside your house and your connection to someone else's network
- The blue line represents their link to the internet

...you will only ever be able to talk to your nas at the highest common speed - so if NAS to router = 100mbps, router to internet upload = 4 mbps, internet download to their router = 8mpbs, their wifi to your laptop = 100mbps... would mean you got a 4mbps connection back to your NAS.

Hopefully this goes some way to answering your question - but it really does depend on usage, your connection speed, someone else's connection speed etc.

Comment: OP's question considers connecting from inside the house, comparing using public IP (perhaps with router configured to forward to the NAS) vs. using the private LAN IP of the NAS directly.

Comment: See https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/20613